# $QR$ Decomposition: Possible motivation behind $Q\,\text{diag}\,R$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to understand better the operations underpinning the creation of polynomial contrasts in ANOVA, and I see that at some point we end up with a matrix where all elements in each column have been raised to a different exponent. The details can be found [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/206345/67822) if they are relevant.

The issue is that at that point, the matrix is $QR$ decomposed, and the diagonal elemens of $R$ are exctracted (the vector of the eigenvalues of the upper triangular $R$), *and* then the $Q$ matrix is multiplied by these eigenvalues placed in isolation in a diagonal matrix: $Q\,\text{diag}(R)$.

The question is, in generic terms, what is the thought behind such an operation? $Q$ and $R$ have different eigenvalues, but obviously the two matrices are related. If you were to multiply them together $QR$ you would return to the original matrix. Instead we get rid of the upper corner of $R$... Strip content out of $R$... Why? What properties is the resultant matrix going to have?